# How to securely provide private SSL keys to Cloud Foundry apps?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have an app that I want to run in Cloud Foundry (specifically, in IBM Bluemix). This app will call out to a number of third-party services/APIs, most of which are not managed via CF services. One of these APIs requires my app to use an SSL key to authenticate, so my app needs access to a private SSL key.

My app is deployed from an automated pipeline (specifically, IBM Bluemix DevOps Pipelines) based off of source from a GitHub repo and some small scripts saved in the pipeline config.

It seems like a bad idea to keep the private key file in the source control, and I don't believe there's anywhere to keep it in the pipeline config, so what are my options for making it available to the app while keeping it secure?

I've read this article: [Keeping secrets – how your cloud application should access credentials and other private data](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2014/10/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/) which says that secrets, passwords, etc, can be made available via environment variables or Cloud Foundry *user-provided services*.

Googling to find out if this is a suitable option for SSL keys, I find this Cloud Foundry Page: [Understanding Cloud Foundry Security](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/security.html) which says "Store SSL keys securely to prevent disclosure, and promptly replace lost or compromised keys.", but doesn't say anything about how to store them securely and make them available to your apps.

**So what options are available to me for storing the private key and making it available to my CF app while not storing it in my source control?**

**Note:** I believe I do *not* want the `cf ssh` functionality, as that is for connecting in to an app (if I understand it correctly), not for an app connecting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed - keeping your key in source control is bad practice.

Bluemix has a service called [Key Protect](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/key-protect?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south) that should provide exactly what you're looking for.

[Docs here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/keymgmt/index.html)

Alternatively there are a number of other 3rd party providers you could use to do this.